# Identify latest file based on version in python

Tags: python

I have a list of `.jar` files in my directory:

```
testapplication-1.0.jar
testapplication-1.1.jar
testapplication-2.0.jar
```

I want to get the latest jar based on the version in the filename, so I want the output to be `testapplication-2.0.jar`. How do we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function that parses the version number from a filename into a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), then use that function as the `key=` parameter to the [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function:

```py
from pathlib import Path

filenames = ["testapplication-1.0.jar", "testapplication-1.1.jar", "testapplication-2.0.jar"]

def parse_version(filename):
    return tuple(int(x) for x in Path(filename).stem.split('-')[-1].split('.')) 

max(filenames, key=parse_version)  # 'testapplication-2.0.jar'
```

If you need something more complicated, like also getting the second-latest version, you could also use the `parse_version` function as the `key=` parameter to the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
from packaging import version

jar_files = ['testapplication-1.0.jar', 'testapplication-1.1.jar', 'testapplication-2.0.jar']

versions = [jar_file.rpartition('.')[0].split('-')[1] for jar_file in jar_files]

_version = versions[0]

for ver in versions[1:]:
    if version.parse(ver) > version.parse(_version):
        _version = ver

print(f'testapplication-{_version}.jar')
```

Comment: I am getting an error No module named 'packaging'. I am trying to test in AWS lambda function. I am using python version 3.6, and I cannot do pip3 install packaging that might be a reason. Any thoughts is greatfully helpful. thanks

Comment: You need to install `packaging` module. @Borris answer fails when you have 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 version files. The function in ```packaging.version``` handles these version.

Comment: @Ghanteyyy which combination exactly doesn't work? because `["testapplication-1.0.1.jar", "testapplication-1.0.2.jar", "testapplication-1.1.jar"]` gets sorted exactly the way it should. Also, my name only has 1 letter "R".