# finding the largest version number file of of many files?

Tags: python, list, integer

Hi I have list of json files in a folder.

```
['user_sample_v001.json', 'user_sample_v002.json', 'user_sample_v105.json']
```

so pythonically I am trying to get the latest version

```
>>> for item in lst:
...  print os.path.splitext(item.split("_")[-1])[0]

v001
v002
v105
```

gives me list of numebrs liks this:

```
>>> for version in versions:
...  number = ""
...  for num in version:
...   if num.isdigit():
...    number = "{0}{1}".format(number, num)
...  nums.append(number)
... 
>>> nums
['001', '002', '105']
```

then I can do max(nums) gives me `'105'`

then I can check like this:

```
for user_sample in lst:
    if max_num in user_sample:
        print user_sample
```

that gives me 'user_sample_v105.json' can it be further more optimized for accuracy and performance  ?

Comment: I would recommend doing: `nums.append(int(number))` so that later `max(nums)` will always work properly.

Comment: btw It looks like you are using `python 2`. It is recommended to upgrade to `python 3`.

Comment: What about just `max(lst)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify latest file based on version in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266951/identify-latest-file-based-on-version-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max()` function with custom `key=` function:

```
import re

lst = ['user_sample_v001.json', 'user_sample_v002.json', 'user_sample_v105.json']

pattern = re.compile(r'_v(\d+)\.json')

m = max(lst, key=lambda k: int(pattern.search(k).group(1)))
print(m)
```

Prints:

```
user_sample_v105.json
```

Comment: would have been nice without lambda.